# SLES release (/etc/os-release) does not match kernel version?

Tags: kernel, sles

I have a system that was supposed to be SLES 15 SP2.
`lsb-release -a` and `/etc/os-release` all confirm.

However  `uname -a` is reporting kernel 4.12.14-94.41-default  (Which is SLES 12 SP4 according to [SUSe support](https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=000019587).

All the files in `/boot` also are showing the same as Kernel.

The system was supposedly upgraded back in May.

I have a utility that I need to load that is complaining about the mismatch.   It's trying to load the SLES 15 SP2 driver but it's the wrong kernel.  If I try to load the SLES 12 driver it says "Wrong OS version"

Any ideas?

Here's the output from `/usr/bin/SUSEConnect`

```
Installed Products:

  SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP2
  (SLES/15.2/x86_64)
  Registered

  Containers Module
  (sle-module-containers/15.2/x86_64)
  Registered

  Legacy Module
  (sle-module-legacy/15.2/x86_64)
  Registered

  Public Cloud Module
  (sle-module-public-cloud/15.2/x86_64)
  Registered

  Web and Scripting Module
  (sle-module-web-scripting/15.2/x86_64)
  Registered

  Basesystem Module
  (sle-module-basesystem/15.2/x86_64)
  Registered

  Server Applications Module
  (sle-module-server-applications/15.2/x86_64)
  Registered

  Desktop Applications Module
  (sle-module-desktop-applications/15.2/x86_64)
  Registered

  Development Tools Module
  (sle-module-development-tools/15.2/x86_64)
  Registered

  Python 2 Module
  (sle-module-python2/15.2/x86_64)
  Registered
```

Output of `cat /etc/products.d/baseproduct`

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<product schemeversion="0">
  <vendor>SUSE</vendor>
  <name>SLES</name>
  <version>15.2</version>
  <baseversion>15</baseversion>
  <patchlevel>2</patchlevel>
  <release>0</release>
  <endoflife></endoflife>
  <arch>x86_64</arch>
  <cpeid>cpe:/o:suse:sles:15:sp2</cpeid>
  <productline>sles</productline>
  <codestream>
    <name>SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15</name>
    <endoflife>2028-07-31</endoflife>
  </codestream>
  <register>
      <target>sle-15-x86_64</target>
  </register>
  <repositories>
      <repository type="update" repoid="obsrepository://build.suse.de/SUSE:Updates:SLE-Product-SLES:15-SP2:x86_64/update" />
      <repository type="update" repoid="obsrepository://build.suse.de/SUSE:Updates:SLE-Product-SLES:15-SP2:x86_64/update_debug" />
      <repository type="update" repoid="obsrepository://build.suse.de/SUSE:Updates:SLE-INSTALLER:15-SP2:x86_64/update" />
      <repository type="pool" repoid="obsproduct://build.suse.de/SUSE:Products:SLE-Product-SLES:15-SP2:x86_64/SLES/15.2/x86_64" />
      <repository type="pool" repoid="obsproduct://build.suse.de/SUSE:Products:SLE-Product-SLES:15-SP2:x86_64/SLES/15.2/x86_64" />
      <repository type="pool" repoid="obsproduct://build.suse.de/SUSE:Products:SLE-Product-SLES:15-SP2:x86_64/SLES/15.2/x86_64" />
  </repositories>
  <summary>SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP2</summary>
  <shortsummary>SLES15-SP2</shortsummary>
  <description>SUSE Linux Enterprise offers a comprehensive
        suite of products built on a single code base.
        The platform addresses business needs from
        the smallest thin-client devices to the world's
        most powerful high-performance computing
        and mainframe servers. SUSE Linux Enterprise
        offers common management tools and technology
        certifications across the platform, and
        each product is enterprise-class.</description>
  <linguas>
    <language>cs</language>
    <language>da</language>
    <language>de</language>
    <language>en</language>
    <language>en_GB</language>
    <language>en_US</language>
    <language>es</language>
    <language>fi</language>
    <language>fr</language>
    <language>hu</language>
    <language>it</language>
    <language>ja</language>
    <language>nb</language>
    <language>nl</language>
    <language>pl</language>
    <language>pt</language>
    <language>pt_BR</language>
    <language>ru</language>
    <language>sv</language>
    <language>zh</language>
    <language>zh_CN</language>
    <language>zh_TW</language>
  </linguas>
  <urls>
    <url name="releasenotes">https://www.suse.com/releasenotes/x86_64/SUSE-SLES/15-SP2/release-notes-sles.rpm</url>
  </urls>
  <buildconfig>
    <producttheme>SLES</producttheme>
  </buildconfig>
  <installconfig>
    <defaultlang>en_US</defaultlang>
    <releasepackage name="sles-release" flag="EQ" version="15.2" release="52.8.2"/>
    <distribution>SUSE_SLE</distribution>
  </installconfig>
  <runtimeconfig/>
  <productdependency relationship="provides" name="SUSE_SLE" baseversion="15" patchlevel="2" flag="EQ"/>
  <productdependency relationship="provides" name="SUSE_SLE-SP2" baseversion="15" patchlevel="2" flag="EQ"/>
</product>
```

Comment: Have you done anything more after upgrading 12->15 from the DVD? Have you product licenses active?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro  Unsure how they did the upgrade.   I didn't do the upgrade and I'm waiting for the guys that did it to responde.   What I know is this is the only one of my SLES boxes that looks like this.   There are some that they didn't clean-up the old Kernel...which I can get around..  But this one seem like it wasn't fully done.

Comment: Please add to the question the output of `sudo /usr/bin/SUSEConnect --status-text` and `sudo cat /etc/products.d/baseproduct`

Comment: Also `sudo zypper sl`

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro   Here the output.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro   Here the output. usr/bin/SUSEConnect --status-text
Installed Products:
------------------------------------------
  SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP2
  (SLES/15.2/x86_64)

Comment: I would advise editing the question with the outputs of all the commands, that output is not the full one. Nevertheless, I suspect you have an active license. Would not a `sudo zypper dup" fix your problem? It it does, I can elaborate in an answer the case for using it.

Comment: Could it be that there is a separate `/boot`partition with a new kernel that isn't mounted right now?

Comment: @U.Windl Actually...I have numerous other issues going on...with this being one of them.   All about prioritization.    Thanks   for the suggestions...investigating further.

Comment: Question has been updated with output of suggested

Comment: Deleted my comment, sorry. Could be /boot, could be something else

Comment: Has anything been done *after* upgrading from DVDs?

Comment: Waiting for my off-shore guys, who actually did the upgrade tell me what the H&LL they did.    Once I find out...I'll share.   We actually had some other systems that had issues with Old modules being active and needed to replace them with the newer ones to get apps to work.. FYI...We are using Azure Migrate to move from AWS to Azure...and MS tool is very picky...(I guess as it should be).